# convert exe application into sis

Tags: exe, symbian, porting

I am working on an application for windows os but I want to port it to Symbian belle os so it will work on multiple operating systems..is there any way or software to edit and convert exe app into sis or sisx file ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, there is no an easy/automatic way of doing that (like Wine for Linux would do).

Long answer - these are two different fileformats which require different loading procedures (OS-specific-ones). Als,o Symbian will normaly run on the hardware architectures different from the one Windows runs (if you meant Desktop Windows application in your question). Not to mention that underlaying APIs are completely different.

Having some experience on both platforms I would comare the porting efforts of such an application to two different projects being developed separately. If it is going to be a long-term maintenance, I would suggest to write an "abstraction layer" and code the application logic to be common to both platforms, separating the platform-dependent details only.